# Pandas resampling data with bigger interval than a whole index range

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, resample

## Situation

I have the folowwing pandas timeseries data:

| date | predicted1 |
| --- | --- |
| 2001-03-13 | 0.994756 |
| 2005-08-22 | 0.551661 |
| 2000-05-07 | 0.001396 |

I need to take into account a case of resampling into bigger interval than a 5 years, for e.g. 10 years:

```
sample = data.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date'])).drop('date', axis=1)['predicted1']
sample.resample('10Y').sum()
```

I get the following:

| date |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-12-31 | 0.001396 |
| 2010-12-31 | 1.546418 |

So resampling function groups data for the first year and separetely for other years.

## Question

How to group all data to the 10 year interval? I want to get smth like this:

| date |  |
| --- | --- |
| 2000-12-31 | 1.5478132011506138 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the reference, closing and label in [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
sample.resample('10Y', origin=sample.index.min(), closed='left', label='left').sum()
```

Output:

```
date
1999-12-31    1.547813
Freq: 10A-DEC, Name: predicted1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: And how to make the beginning of the interval 2000-01-01? Maybe there is a way to add some one-day offset

Comment: The easiest is probably to post process the index

Comment: As I understood, it is possible by adding `loffset='d'` to the params of resample function. @mozway thank you!